How to Request a New API Key for TinyMCE?
I need to obtain a new API key for TinyMCE. Currently, I have an old API key that I would like to replace with a new one. What are the steps to request a new API key from TinyMCE?
When I asked Tiny via the chatbox, I received this message:

Our Stack Overflow community may be able to help! Ask your question here. Also, our Docs are updated regularly and may provide helpful answers.

I also tried emailing support and received this response:

Hi,
Thanks for reaching out. If you're looking to access technical support, our documentation is a great resource for our free users. Stack Overflow is also a great resource as well. If you need to report a bug, please submit it to GitHub.
We do offer formal technical support options to our paid subscribers.
Is this something you'd be interested in exploring?

I did reply to the email with no response.
I looked through the documentation and the TinyMCE admin settings but could not find how to request a new API key.
So, I'm asking the question here in hopes someone can point me in the right direction.
Thank you for your help!

We currently offer no way for users of our Cloud platform to rotate API keys.
API keys are visible to anyone/everyone using your application - they are not like a public key / private key pair.  Why do you want to rotate the API key?

I was using a personal API key for a project that has now been transferred to a client. I informed them that they would need to create and use their own API key when the project goes live in production. However, my personal API key is still in the code repository. I want to rotate my key to avoid them accidentally using it.

You can simply remove their domain from your list of allowed domains and they will no longer be able to use your API key.

I have done that, but it does not prevent them from using the API key for localhost, as that domain cannot be removed. I appreciate your response. If rotating the API key is not possible at this time, I will have to manage with the current situation.
